# peer - to - peer chat with AsyncSocket class

Tags: cocoa, client-server, chat, p2p, asyncsocket

I want to use AsyncSocket class for peer - to - peer chat. I have been able to make a sample chat application where one user can communicate with other user by transmitting messages to server and then from server to other user(s) by using it, but I am finding it some what difficult to manage sockets established in peer - to - peer chat and getting mixed up in server and client delegates provided by AsyncSocket class when both are implemented at one node.

I tried to search some sample code over net which uses AsyncSocket class to establish peer -to -peer chat, but unable to find any!

Moreover, I want to know will it be good to use AsyncSocket class for my requirements (establishing peer - peer chat, video conferencing, voice chat) or there is any better option available?

Thanks for any help,

Miraaj